# Update vuejs model value using jquery-chosen plugin

Tags: jquery-chosen, vue.js

Trying to use [jquery-chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) with vue, the problem is that this plugin hides the actual select that I applied `v-model`, so when I select a value vue doesn't recognize it as a select change event and model value is not updated.

The value of the select is being changed actually when I select something, I've inspected this with console.log to see the selected value.

http://jsfiddle.net/qfy6s9Lj/3/

I could do `vm.$data.city = $('.cs-select').val()`, [that](http://jsfiddle.net/qfy6s9Lj/4/) seems to work,
But is there another option? If the value of the select was changed why vue doesn't see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/qfy6s9Lj/5/

```
<div id='search-results'>
    Vue model value <br>
    {{city}}
    <hr>
    Select value:
    <select class="cs-select" v-chosen>
       <option value="Toronto">Toronto</option>
       <option value="Orleans">Orleans</option>
    </select>
</div>

Vue.directive('chosen', {
    bind: function () {
        var vm = this.vm;
        this.el.options = vm.cities;
        this.el.value = vm.city;       

        $(this.el).chosen({
            inherit_select_classes: true,
            width: '30%',
            disable_search_threshold: 999})
        .change( function() {
             vm.city = this.el.value;
         }.bind(this)
      );
    }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
      city: 'Toronto',
      cities: ['Toronto', 'Orleans']
  }
}).$mount("#search-results");
```

**UPDATE: an even better solution** (thanks to simplesmiler):
http://jsfiddle.net/simplesmiler/qfy6s9Lj/8/

Comment: it seems that this doesn't work with select tag that has an attribute of multiple (multiselect).

Answer (score 4):

@swift's answer got pretty close, but as @bertrand pointed out, it doesn't work for multiselects. I've worked something out that works with both cases: http://jsfiddle.net/seanwash/sz8s99xx/

I would have just commented but I don't have enough rep to do so.

```js
Vue.directive('chosen', {
    twoWay: true, // note the two-way binding
    bind: function () {
        $(this.el)
            .chosen({
                inherit_select_classes: true,
                width: '30%',
                disable_search_threshold: 999
            })
            .change(function(ev) {
                // two-way set
                // Construct array of selected options
                var i, len, option, ref;
                var values = [];
                ref = this.el.selectedOptions;
                for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
                    option = ref[i];
                    values.push(option.value)
                }
                
                this.set(values);
                
            }.bind(this));
    },
    update: function(nv, ov) {
        // note that we have to notify chosen about update
        $(this.el).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
      city: 'Toronto',
      cities: [{text: 'Toronto', value: 'Toronto'}, 
               {text: 'Orleans', value: 'Orleans'}]
  }
}).$mount("#search-results");
```

Comment: One more time... Here's an update (in coffeescript) that returns an array if the select is a multi select and a string if it's not: http://jsfiddle.net/seanwash/wmrkrdzr/1/

Comment: I haven't tried. I've been using https://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/ which has been great so far.

Answer (score 3):

I am opened for other suggestions, but for the time-being I did it this way:

**html**

```
<div id='search-results'>
    {{city}}
    <select class="cs-select" v-model='city'>
        <option value="Toronto">Toronto</option>
        <option value="Orleans">Orleans</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**js**

```
window.vm = new Vue({
  el: '#search-results',
  data: {
    city: 'Toronto',
  }
})

$('.cs-select').chosen({
    inherit_select_classes: true,
    width: '30%'
}).change( function() {
    vm.$data.city = $('.cs-select').val()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Be advised this doesn't work from within a `v-for` loop. A related question that deals with that is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45384059/135101).

Going off of @kaktuspalme's solution, and with help from my friend Joe Fleming, I came up with a solution that works with Vue 2 and allows single and multiple selections:

```js
Vue.directive('chosen', {
    inserted: function(el, binding, vnode) {
        jQuery(el).chosen().change(function(event, change) {
            if (Array.isArray(binding.value)) {
                var selected = binding.value;
                if (change.hasOwnProperty('selected')) {
                    selected.push(change.selected);
                } else {
                    selected.splice(selected.indexOf(change.deselected), 1);
                }
            } else {
                var keys = binding.expression.split('.');
                var pointer = vnode.context;
                while (keys.length > 1)
                    pointer = pointer[keys.shift()];
                pointer[keys[0]] = change.selected;
            }
        });
    },
    componentUpdated: function(el, binding) {
        jQuery(el).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
});
```

Use it like this:

```
<select v-model="mymodel" v-chosen="mymodel">...</select>
```

It works with `multiple="multiple"` and even with nested state, e.g.:

```
<select v-model="nested.mymodel" v-chosen="nested.mymodel">...</select>
```

See the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tylercollier/bvvvgyp0/5/

Answer (score 2):

I made an update for vue2.

```
Vue.directive('chosen', {
    selected: null,
    inserted: function (el, binding) {
        selected = binding.value;
        $(el).chosen().change(function(event, change) {
            if(change.hasOwnProperty('selected')) {
                selected.push(change.selected);
            } else {
                selected.splice(selected.indexOf(change.deselected), 1);
            }
        });
    },
    componentUpdated: function(el, binding) {
        selected = binding.value;           
        $(el).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
});

var vm = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      selected: [],
      cities: [{id: 1, value: "Toronto"}, {id: 2, value: "Orleans"}, {id: 3, value: "Bern"}]
   }
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/kaktuspalme/zenksm2b/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the fiddle!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for non-`multiple` select elements. Also, what is the `selected: null`? That seems superfluous? And where you write `selected = binding.value`, aren't you setting a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Code taken from @kaktuspalme answer. It works with non-multiple elements now and only for non-multiple.

```
 Vue.directive('chosensingle', {

inserted: function (el, binding) {
    var selected = binding.value;

    $(el).chosen().change(function(event, change) {

        if(change.hasOwnProperty('selected')) {
            selected.value = change.selected;                
        } else {
            selected.value  ='';
        }
    });
},
componentUpdated: function(el, binding) {

    $(el).trigger("chosen:updated");
}
});
```

Comments from  @Tyler Collier  are taken into account

But be carefully,property you use in v-model should be defined as array , e.g. applicantId: [] otherwise it doesn't work