# Access v-for model used within Vue 2 custom directive

Tags: vuejs2

## Question

How can I update the model data used within a Vue 2 custom directive?

Setup:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <select my-directive="item">...</select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So let's say I have a directive with a hook like this:

```js
Vue.directive('chosenjs', {
  inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    // Here, I'm setting up a callback with the jQuery Chosen library, but this could be any callback.
    jQuery(el).chosen().change(function(event, change) {
      // CODE HERE...
    });
  }
});
```

In the `CODE HERE...` section, if `binding.value` is a pointer (array/object), then this is straight-forward. For example, for an array, I'd do e.g. `binding.value.push(someValue)`, and Vue's observable will handle it. But if the value is a primitive, then what can be done?

If the directive is *not* used within a `v-for` loop, you can use the `vnode` to modify the data in the component. It works great as I show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362097/135101).

But if it *is* in a `v-for`, it seems there's no way. Even with access to the `binding.expression`, there's no way to get at the v-for item.

## Background

I'm trying to work with Vue and the ChosenJS jQuery library. I got most of the way there with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362097/135101), but there is a bug when the directive is used within a `v-for` loop.

Comment: Are you married to a directive? In most cases I recommend a component over a directive for jQuery plugins in Vue 2. Using a directive is very Vue 1.

Comment: @BertEvans Nope, not married. I went with a directive because of that stackoverflow answer that I linked. I'd like to keep the markup similar to how my client would use ChosenJS without Vue, but this client is technical and could cope.

Comment: I previously wrote a small component for chosen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641153/vue-2-with-jquery-chosen/44642504#44642504).  I also apparently updated a directive [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286008/vue2js-how-to-propagate-selected-index-with-chosen-select-value-in-a-direcitve/44287409#44287409) though I didn't remember it and I don't know if it has the same issue as yours above.

Comment: @Bert It turns out I think I should be married _for this question_. I think the approach using a component might be the right one and I'll explore that soon. If I use a component, I can upvote the other answer you linked. But I think this question is separately useful due to its explicit requirement of a directive.